# Chaining selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, method-chaining

I'm a guy used to mootools' way of chaining selectors, and I can't seem to find anywhere how to do the same in jQuery.
Suppose I have a *select element* in the `selectObj` variable. What I need is to get the last option in that select.
In mootools I would have done something like:

```
var option = $(selectObj).getElement('nth-child(last)')
```

Can I do something similar, or what is the way of getting that last `option` in jQuery?

PS. I know about the [parent > child selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild), but I can't really use it because I don't know what selector has been used to get the `select`. I only have the resulting element.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var option = $(selectObj).children(":last");
```

will return the last child of any element

Comment: In fact most traversal operations in jQuery (siblings, find, parents, children, etc) allow an optional filter expression to be specified.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. I only searched the "selectors" part of the doc and not the traversing one. I don't know why though. Thanks.

Answer (score 51):

```
$(selectObj).find(':last')
```

You can use [`find`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr) to perform another query within the current query.

In general, you can check out the [Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) and [Traversal](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) pages on jQuery docs when you're trying to figure out how to select something.

Comment: I only searched the "selectors" part of the doc and not the "traversing" one. I think cobbal's solution fits better though.

Comment: This is the more general solution to the problem, and the one I was looking for when I searched and found this question.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick aside, `.find` is one of the slowest selectors: http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-find-class.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `.last()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the [:last Selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/last)

```
$("tr:last").stuff()
```

Will do stuff to the last row in a table.